# Specifying per-project code analysis rules in msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution containing multiple projects. A subset of those projects are external libraries which are built from source. In visual studio, I have different rulesets for those external projects than the non-external projects. Visual studio allows me to run code analysis across the whole solution using the per-project rules, however I can't find a way do this in msbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click a project -> Properties -> Code Analysis -> check the checkbox named Enable Code Analysis on Build -> on ‘Run this rule set’, select the rule set as you want.  You could do the same operation on other projects. Then build you solution, it will run different Code Analysis as your selecting.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this led me down the path of creating a seperate build configuration,  setting 'Enable Code Analysis on Build' and using the new build configs.